# Recurrence Relation based on Vectors

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I am new to *Mathematica*. 
I try to solve a recurrence relation based on vectors.
So `a[n]` is a vector for all `n` (as well as `b[n]` and `c[n]`).
The value for `a[n]` depends on the Euclidean norm of `a[n-1]` (see code below).

My code below, however, does not work.
Do I have to tell *Mathematica* explicitly that I am working on vectors? How can I do this? Is *Mathematica* in general able to solve a recurrence like this?

Thanks in advance!

```
 RSolve[{b[n] == 1/2 a[n - 1] + 1/2 c[n - 1], 
  a[n] == 1/(2*Norm[a[n - 1]])a[n-1] + 1/2 b[n - 1], 
  c[n] == 1/2 b[n - 1] + 1/(2 Norm[c[n - 1]]) c[n - 1]}, {a[n], b[n], 
  c[n]}, n]
```

Comment: Knowing that a,b,c are vectors you could  write `a[n-1].a[n-1]` instead of `Norm[a[n-1]]` . But the second and third equation might be inconsistent, because here you add scalar and vector on the right side.

Comment: There was a missing factor after the first norm occurrence. I fixed this now.

Comment: Consider doing it numerically.